# converting JodaTime to Long Integer format

Tags: java, jodatime

hello I had date format which i use in a API call in Long integer format. That API call does not support date in any other format and it should as follows.

```
public static long start_date=20140401101010L;
    public static long end_date=20140430101010L;
```

I had to make some changes in that date, so i changed that date into JodaDate format as like the below code.

```
DateTime startDateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(String.valueOf(start_date)); 
DateTime endDateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(String.valueOf(end_date));
```

This is how we convert normal variable to DateTime object. so how can i do the opposite.? If i have a JodaTime 2014-04-30T10:10:10.000+05:30 and i want to change that time to this format which is as a Long integer. 20140430101010L . I want to do this because i am doing an API program and the url parameter has time and which support only the above format and not in JodaTime.

Comment: Can you please post the definition of your `formatter` - is it a `SimpleDateFormat`, and what is the format string (YYYY MM etc...)?

Comment: I want to change to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format

Comment: If it's a "url parameter", why does it need to be a long?

Comment: ... because "url parameters" are strings, not longs.

Answer (score 3):

Format your joda time object as a string, and then convert to a long.

You would need a formatter that outputs in the format you want

```
DateTimeFormatter  formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String formatted = formatter.format(datetime);
long lvalue = Long.parseLong(formatted).longValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use a [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) to build the String then parse it as a Long.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need a `long` in that format, which i would seriously question:

```
long dateTimeLong = year    * 10000000000L
                  + month   *   100000000L
                  + date    *     1000000L
                  + hours   *       10000L
                  + minutes *         100L
                  + seconds *           1L;
```

---

You say you need an URL parameter though, which is a string, and not a long. So just use

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String dateTimeString = formatter.print(dateTime);
```

Comment: @vikingsteve: No, they are two different examples. The first example if sarath needs a long which i doubt since she says it's for "the url parameter", and the second example for a string, which i think should be fine for a url parameter.

Comment: Ok, he said his API only supports `Long` parameters - if he needs to convert to Long then he can tell us.

Comment: @vikingsteve: So what's your take on what "the url parameter has time and which support only the above format" means then? How is a url parameter not a string?

Comment: guys its in Long because URL parameter just support this format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS . its a 14 digit number and it cannot be integer so i had to give as long.

Comment: What do you mean "URL parameter"? URL parameters are strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DateConverter {
    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    private final DateTime dateTime;

    public DateConverter(DateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    private Long toLong() {
        return Long.valueOf(dateTime.toString(formatter));
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(new DateConverter(DateTime.now()).toLong());
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
20140623131922

Process finished with exit code 0
```